# Extract numbers between two patterns javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

I am trying to extract a set of numbers from a url. The string is betwen the word "region" and word "all". 
The url is :
http://my.site.com/theme/feature/region/227-84/all/country-south

The regular expression which I have built is :

```
var tmp = $(this).attr('link').match("(?=region/).*?(?=/all)");
```

The regex is extracting the correct portion of numbers but is always sticking the region to numbers so the extracted string become :

```
"region/227-84"
```

While I wannt to get only the numbers:

```
"227-84"
```

Comment: remove the lookaheads and use a capture group.

Comment: `match` returns an array, right? So can't you do `match(...)[1]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's including the substring "region/" because the positive lookahead `(?=region\/)` is matching the character *before* "region/". Since JavaScript doesn't have lookbehinds, the easiest option would be to remove the lookaheads and use a capturing group in order to extract the middle portion:

```
/region\/([^\/]*)\/all/
```

or if there are slashes between the patterns:

```
/region\/(.*?)\/all/
```

Usage:

```
var match = $(this).attr('link').match(/region\/([^\/]*)\/all/);
var result = match ? match[1] : null;

console.log(result); // "227-84"
```

If there is a match, the `.match()` method returns an array. In this case it would return:

```
["region/227-84/all", "227-84"] // match
```

The first capturing group has an index of one (i.e., `match ? match[1] : null`). In this case, the ternary operator is simply used to check if there was actually a match before accessing the array (otherwise an error would be thrown if there wasn't a match).

Comment: Shrinking the above solution into one line by appending the array key to initial regex:        var match = $(this).attr('link').match("/region\/(.*?)\/all/")[1];

Answer (score 0):

If you already know that the size of the string you are looking for you could do this:

```
......(?=\/all)
```